# Dynamic update of displayed quantities on a Plot within manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate, dynamic

I'll admit that I only skimmed some other threads about this. They seem rather complicated in contrast to my simple problem. I have two lines in space defined by a two-by-two coefficient matrix. I intend to manipulate on a single entry, say the (1,2)-element. In the static case I worked to display the intersection point, between the two lines, on the graph. The goal is to watch the point of intersection change as the parameter changes.  My code:

```
a = 1;
f = 3;
c = 2;
d = 1;
g = -1;

Line1 :=  a  x + b y ;
Line2 :=  c x + d y;
IntersectionPoint := Solve[Line1 == f && Line2 == g, {x, y}]
xIntersection := x /. IntersectionPoint[[1]][[1]] 
yIntersection := y /. IntersectionPoint[[1]][[2]] 

Manipulate[ContourPlot[{a x + b y == f, c x + d y == g}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
                PlotLegends -> True, Axes -> True, 
                AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
                Epilog -> {{Text[StringJoin["Point of Intersection:", " 
                           (x,y)=(", ToString[ N[xIntersection]], 
                            ",", ToString[N[yIntersection]] , ")"], 
                           Scaled[{.62, .8}]]}}], {b, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: Update: I posted before I asked my question. If you run the above code then you will see a symbolic result displayed on the screen that does not take into account the current value of the manipulated parameter 'b'. I would like the numerical value of the intersection point displayed through the manipulated values.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: What is the problem here? Can you spell out what does work, and what  doesn't? What would you like help with?

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[{
  m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
  Column[{r = Thread[m.{x, y} == {f, g}], s = LinearSolve[m, {f, g}]}],
  ContourPlot[Evaluate@r, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> s]}, {{b, 3}, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]